# Java Error when importing from javafx when using RMI

Tags: java, javafx, program-entry-point, stage

When i've added the attribute `private Stage stage = new Stage();` to one class in my project `import javafx.stage.Stage;` i get the following error when running main. Do i have to modify something in the RMI configuration to not get this error?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.ServerError: Error occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at javafx.stage.Window.<init>(Window.java:1191)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.<init>(Stage.java:239)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.<init>(Stage.java:227)
    at it.polimi.ingsw.pcGC_44.Player.<init>(Player.java:46)
    at it.polimi.ingsw.pcGC_44.Controller.updateFromView(Controller.java:204)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
   ...

  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This operation is permitted on the event thread only; currentThread = RMI TCP Connection(2)-10.169.221.232
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.checkEventThread(Application.java:443)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Screen.setEventHandler(Screen.java:285)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.setScreenConfigurationListener(QuantumToolkit.java:667)
    at javafx.stage.Screen.<clinit>(Screen.java:79)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory: you are trying to create a `Stage` from a background thread (i.e. not the FX Application Thread). That operation is only permitted on the FX Application Thread.

Comment: so all the classes that use the javafx library need to extend application?

Comment: Uh, no. I have no idea how you came to that conclusion from my previous comment. The `Application` class represents the entire application (specifically its lifecycle): you should only have one `Application` subclass in your application.

Comment: which have to be the main right? so only in there i can have stages.

Comment: You can create a `Stage` in any class you like. You just have to do so on the FX Application Thread.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with [tag:rmi]. It's rather strange to have an RMI server that has a GUI.